# syntax error In Maxima load and batch

Tags: maxima

I saved a file using

save("/Users/iaingray/.maxima/temp.mac",[1,2]);

which is in my file_search_maxima; path

I then tried  load(temp); and batch(temp); which both failed  with

stdin:1:incorrect syntax: Premature termination of input at ;.

Maxima 5.30.0, imaxima(emacs) and wxMaxima, Mac OSX 10.9.1

Any suggestions? Iain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`save` creates a Lisp file, not a Maxima file. Give the file a name which ends with `.lisp` and load it via `load`.